# Extracting from array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I am learning PHP and I'm trying to understand the array below,
I need to grab **content-type**, it should give me

1. **text/xml;charset=UTF-8**  and then
2. grab the encoding which is **UTF-8**

Anyone good with arrays could you please help?

```
array(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 17:10:12 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache
    [3] => X-Gas_TTL: 900
    [4] => Cache-Control: max-age=900
    [5] => X-GasHost: gas1.usw
    [6] => X-Cooking-With: Gasoline-Local
    [7] => X-Gasoline-Age: 844
    [8] => Last-Modified: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 16:56:08 GMT
    [9] => Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
    [10] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
)
```

Thank you in advance

Regards,
Mona

Comment: How are you receiving this weird array in the first place? Can you show us the code?

Comment: Hi Murali, i am using snoopy class which will return this array.

Comment: Looks like [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/get_headers) without associative $format flag.

Comment: Change `get_headers()` to use the second parameter, access `$arr['Content-Type']`, split the string on `=` and take the second part.

Comment: Or if you're fine with code that is *not* readable, maintainable, and hacky, you can do something like: `$charset = explode('=',array_values(preg_grep('/Content-Type/', $array))[0])[1];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .*?Content-Type:\s*(.*?=(.*?))\n.*
```

With s flag on this will give what's required.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bJ6rZ5/1

Comment: thank you vis.. could you please provide me complete statement i should use. thank you

Comment: preg_match('/.*?Content-Type:\s*(.*?=(.*?))\n.*/s', $text, $match);
echo $match[0]; Try something like this.

Comment: $text is array here so prey_match does not accept array.

Comment: The you can simply loop through the array and apply regex to each line without s flag.

Comment: How about just using `preg_grep()`

Answer (score -1):

The array must be in a variable ( I assume, since you seem to have printed it ), so you simply print/echo the value you're after.

```
echo $someArrayVariable[9];
```

Where someArrayVariable is a variable that contains the array.

That is assuming it is in a variable in the first place.

Comment: This also assumes the index of `Content-type` is already known at `[9]` - I think that's the point though - it has to be found first.

Comment: Nope it won't output what OP is expecting